# Cloning a large graph effeciently

Tags: algorithm, graph

Suppose we have a very large graph. Like facebook users graph. How can we efficiently create a clone of such graph.  Is there any standard efficient algorithm ?

I am looking for an algorithm.We can assume that the graph is main memory.

Comment: More data is needed. How is the graph represented? Where is it stored (RAM? disk? distributed on something like [GFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_File_System)?) Does it contain any more data other then edges and vertices? (some meta-data for example?)

Answer (score 2):

For 'facebook sizes', it is probably on disk. If you *really* have to copy, the fastest way is by not introducing seeks. Usually that means simply copying the files.

Either way I would probably not copy it at all, but copy-on-write. In other words: use the objects you had and store the context, but as soon as you write to the object from within another context, you create a copy.

Comment: +1, though I have a problem with `it is probably on disk`. It might be distributed on several machines (on the RAM of each) to allow fast access. This is how google index is stored, for example.

Comment: Most people don't have 100K machines like Google, hence the 'probably'.

Answer (score 0):

There really is no way to "clone" N number of bytes with less than N operations. I don't think that there is any method that is particularly efficient. Whatever the total number of bytes your graph takes, that is how much time it will take to clone it.

Comment: Though you are going to need `N` operations, how you do them might be an issue. For example, if the data is stored on disk - sequential access is MUCH faster then random access. The things get much more complex when you deal with a data which is distributed on multiple machines.

Comment: He says clone a graph with a fixed structure, not design it to be easily cloned. Unless you change the design of the graph, the method of cloning doesn't matter **much** I think. And if it's on disk, why not just copy the files?